# Vector iterator type unknown

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm learning C++ and this is the first time I work with iterators

I have written down this code:

```
std::pair<max, max> ConvertToAStarMap::GetLimits(std::string map)
{
    // Init max and min variables.
    int max_x = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int min_x = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    int max_y = max_x;
    int min_y = min_x;

    std::vector<std::string> map_cells = ConvertToAStarMap::split(map, ';');

    for (std::string::iterator it = map_cells.begin(); it != map_cells.end(); ++it)
}
```

And I get this error:

```
ConvertToAStarMap.cpp: In member function ‘std::pair<max, max> ConvertToAStarMap::GetLimits(std::__cxx11::string)’:
ConvertToAStarMap.cpp:31:52: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ requested
     for (std::string::iterator it = map_cells.begin(); it != map_cells.end(); ++it)
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
ConvertToAStarMap.cpp:31:59: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ and ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >}’)
     for (std::string::iterator it = map_cells.begin(); it != map_cells.end(); ++it)
                                                        ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is wrong? I don't understand it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand that this is a beginner's mistake, but this is a valid and well-formulated question. I think that OP deserves a proper answer, as easy as it can be to answer that for an experienced C++ programmers.

Comment: I don't think it is a typo. This question comes from misunderstanding how the iterator types of a vector works, something that is easy to happen to a beginner (especially with C++'s verbose iterator types). A typo would be a simple syntax error.

Comment: @VansFannel Meta post related to this question; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387751/is-this-site-for-enthusiasts-or-for-experts-only-for-helpers-or-documenters (Don't expect an answer about downvotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest to do is:

```
for (const auto& cell : map_cells)
```

If you don't want to use the range based for loop :

```
for (auto it = map_cells.begin();......
```

The problem is that You want to iterate over the vector, not over the string, so it should be:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = map_cells.begin();......
```

This information is available in the  error in point 2. :

1. error: conversion from
2. `‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator`
3. {aka `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >`}’
4. to non-scalar type
5. ‘`std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator`
6. {aka `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >`}’

Comment: I'd just like to add that `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` is just the completed type for `std::string`, so a simplified error message would be `error: conversion from ‘std::vector<std::string>::iterator’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string::iterator'`... The error messages are one of the worst parts of C++ :(